# Why was nested list nested a level deeper with just a comma at the end of the line

Tags: python-3.x

I ran into an odd syntax issue in python 3.9.1 (might be others) and I can't find a reason for it in the documentation or here. I'm just curious as to why it happened.

I have a function which returns a list:

```
def func():
    return 1,2,3,4
```

I was creating a dictionary key for later use, and I wanted the value to be a nested list:

```
dict = {key1:[func()], key2: [func(), func()]}
```

the plan was to pass the values to another function which would iterate over the list of list. The final function would work whatever was in the outer list, 0, 1, many.

In my code I had to update the keys before I made the working function call.

```
dict[key1] = [func()],  #<== final comma
```

It was the final comma in the value assignment which is my question. I had copied the dictionary building statement part for that key, and left in the comma. It created a list within a list within a list. Removing the comma got the desired result a list of lists.  I just can't find any documentation as to why that behavior happened. Can anyone explain it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trailing comma is the syntax for a 1-tuple. This is usually used inside parentheses:

```
threetuple = (1, 2, 3)
twotuple = (1, 2)
onetuple = (1,)
literal = (1)   # evaluates to the integer 1, not to a tuple
```

but python's syntax allows it in any block where it's not causing ambiguity, including outside of parentheses:

```
threetuple = 1, 2, 3
twotuple = 1, 2
onetuple = 1,
literal = 1
```

This is what's happening to you - when you do

```
dict[key1] = [func()],
```

you're assigning a *one-tuple* which contains a *single-element list* which contains `func()`.

---

Place the trailing comma *inside* the square brackets, and you'll be fine:

```
dict[key1] = [func(),]
```

This is standard list syntax, and is allowed for any length of list or tuple - it's only *required* when you're writing a one-tuple literal, because otherwise there's no way for python to know you mean it to be a one-tuple.

Comment: Thanks your for the clear explanation.I did finally find the manual's reference to the comma for a one-tuple (build-in Types - Tuples), after three days of searching for some hint as to why.